# How to set an object as an out parameter?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have written a procedure in PL/SQL and want to return a EMP type object. Is it possible to do that? If yes, how can I do it?

Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE get_emp_rs (p_deptno    IN  emp.deptno%TYPE,
                      p_recordset OUT emp_det) AS

    emp_details emp_det;
BEGIN 
  OPEN p_recordset FOR
    SELECT ename,
           empno
    FROM   emp
    WHERE  deptno = p_deptno
    ORDER BY ename;

   fetch p_recordset into emp_details; 
   --exit when p_recordset%notfound;
   --end loop;
   --for indx in p_recordset
   --loop
   emp_details.ename:= 'test';
   --end loop;
END get_emp_rs;
/

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
    DECLARE
      l_cursor  emp_det;
      --l_cur emp_det;
      --l_ename   emp.ename%TYPE;
      --l_empno   emp.empno%TYPE;
      l_deptno  emp.deptno%TYPE;
    BEGIN
     l_cur:=get_emp_rs ('30',
                  l_cursor);
                dbms_output.put_line('low');
      /*LOOP 
        FETCH l_cursor
        INTO  l_ename, l_empno, l_deptno;
        EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;*/
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(l_cursor.ename || ' | ' || l_cursor.empno);
    end;
    /
```

I want to get the `ename` and `empno` after finally update in the procedure.
How can I do it? If there is any better way of doing this please suggest me.

And also please suggest me how I can do it in this way. I cannot use any functions here that's the only obligation. Also please let me know if there is a way of doing this using.

Comment: How is `emp_det` declared? You said it's an object but then `l_cursor` suggests it's a ref cursor?

Comment: emp_det is a object type I created. It has two attributes ename and empo. If I use lcursor as a refcursor is there a way to return the recordset through it.

Answer (score 0):

In your example (Table EMP) a single EMP Record shouldn't be selected by the department number. Use the EMPNO instead.

The following is a quick solution and hopefully self-explainable:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
CLEAR;

--Define the dataset object
CREATE TYPE EMP_DET AS OBJECT (
 EMPNO NUMBER(4),
 ENAME VARCHAR2(10)
);
/

--Define a collection of dataset objects
CREATE TYPE EMP_DET_LIST IS TABLE OF EMP_DET;
/


--Get a SINGLE record into the OUT-Variable identified by EMP PK EMPNO
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_EMP_RS(P_EMPNO     IN EMP.EMPNO%TYPE,
                                       P_RECORDSET IN OUT EMP_DET) AS
BEGIN
  --Create the return object inside SQL
  SELECT EMP_DET(EMPNO, ENAME)
  INTO   P_RECORDSET
  FROM   EMP
  WHERE  EMPNO = P_EMPNO;

  P_RECORDSET.ENAME := 'test';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    --Return NULL if employee not found
    P_RECORDSET := NULL;
END GET_EMP_RS;
/

--Get a LIST OF employees by department
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_EMP_LIST(P_DEPTNO     IN EMP.DEPTNO%TYPE,
                                         P_RECORDLIST OUT EMP_DET_LIST) AS
  TYPE C_CURSOR IS REF CURSOR; -- <-- For the explicit cursor solution only
  C_EMP_RS C_CURSOR;           -- <-- For the explicit cursor solution only
  V_RS     EMP_DET;            -- <-- For the explicit cursor solution only

BEGIN
  --Initialize out object
  P_RECORDLIST := EMP_DET_LIST();

  --Create the return object inside SQL
  --via bulk collect
  /*
  SELECT EMP_DET(EMPNO,ENAME)
  BULK COLLECT INTO INTO P_RECORDLIST
  FROM   EMP
  WHERE  DEPTNO = P_DEPTNO;
  */

  --with manipulation of records
  --use a FOR-LOOP with implizit cursor
  /*
  FOR L_RS IN (SELECT EMP_DET(EMPNO, ENAME) EMP_RS
               FROM   EMP
               WHERE  DEPTNO = P_DEPTNO) LOOP
    L_RS.EMP_RS.ENAME := 'TEST';
    P_RECORDLIST.EXTEND;
    P_RECORDLIST(P_RECORDLIST.LAST) := L_RS.EMP_RS;
    NULL;
  END LOOP;
  */

  --or define an explicit cursor and LOOP-FETCH

  OPEN C_EMP_RS FOR
    SELECT EMP_DET(EMPNO, ENAME) EMP_RS
    FROM   EMP
    WHERE  DEPTNO = P_DEPTNO;
  LOOP
    FETCH C_EMP_RS
      INTO V_RS;
    EXIT WHEN C_EMP_RS%NOTFOUND;
    V_RS.ENAME := 'TEST';
    P_RECORDLIST.EXTEND;
    P_RECORDLIST(P_RECORDLIST.LAST) := V_RS;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE C_EMP_RS;

END GET_EMP_LIST;
/

--**************************
-- Test 
--**************************
DECLARE
  L_CURSOR EMP_DET;
  L_LIST   EMP_DET_LIST;
BEGIN

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---- Single EMP ----');

  GET_EMP_RS(7369, L_CURSOR);

  IF (L_CURSOR IS NOT NULL) THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_CURSOR.ENAME || ' | ' || L_CURSOR.EMPNO);
  END IF;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---- EMP List ----');

  GET_EMP_LIST(30, L_LIST);

  IF (L_LIST.count > 0 ) THEN
    FOR L_I IN L_LIST.FIRST .. L_LIST.LAST LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(L_LIST(L_I).ENAME || ' | ' || L_LIST(L_I).EMPNO);

    END LOOP;
  END IF;

END;
/


DROP PROCEDURE GET_EMP_RS;
DROP PROCEDURE GET_EMP_LIST;
DROP TYPE EMP_DET_LIST;
DROP TYPE EMP_DET;
```

Output:

```
---- Single EMP ----
test | 7369
---- EMP List ----
TEST | 7499
TEST | 7521
TEST | 7654
TEST | 7698
TEST | 7844
TEST | 7900

SQL>
```